# Azure Traffic Manager TCP probe on Azure Container Instance false positive

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-traffic-manager

We have a container running in Azure using ACI. We expose port 57200 on the host and forward that to the container running our app on port 57200. We bind 57200:57200.

We are using Azure Traffic Manager to load balance between 2 instances of our container leveraging a TCP probes. The issue is, regardless of the state of our containers if the host is up and running the probe will be a success as the host accepts the TCP connection so it doesn't matter the state of the container.

How can I use a TCP prob against a container if this is how it works? I don't see away to make this work. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: ACI is a serverless offer. I do believe when your container is not running, the Traffic Manager probe can't get a reply from your container which is the reason for the false positive. You'd either need to use a different container service or a different probe

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio If the host has to forward request to the container but the host has to accept the TCP connection in order to do so, it doesn't matter the state of the container because the TCP connection was already accepted by the host so traffic manager see that as an UP.

Comment: not sure if I understood the problem. I had the impression Traffic Manager would not consider the state as health and that was the reason of the false positive. I would need to inspect or try to reproduce this issue and figure out a work around/fix/solution for this.

Comment: I had the same impression. If the container was terminated the TCP connection would not succeed. But from what I can tell, the HOST accepts the connection and thats a TCP handshake and traffic manager counts it as an up.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the 'Tolerated number of failures' and 'Probe timeout' properties?

Comment: From my testing, if you deploy an ACI and bind a port, let say 57200:5700,  do not have a container listening on the internal port of 57200 you can still connect to that HOST on 57200 and it will succeed as the HOST will just accept the connection.

Answer (score 0):

•   Containers contain instances of applications that run on erstwhile selected images of required type. Thus, the instance itself uses resources assigned to that container group depending on the application usage as the resources assigned to that container are shared amongst the container instances running inside it, including the virtual network subnets assigned to that container if more than one instance is running.

Thus, if more than one instance of a container is running in a container group, the resources shared in that container group will trigger an activity log alert accordingly as they are directly mapped to the container resources, thus, the state of the instance itself becomes the state of the container group which in turn is acknowledged and shown by the TCP health probe on the Azure traffic manager.

A much more enhanced, managed, and efficient liveness as well as a readiness probe can be used for this purpose to check the state of container by deploying it through ‘yaml’ template by including the below parameters in the container deployment yaml file. These probes depend on the existence of ‘ready’ file in the ‘/tmp’ directory of the container, i.e., if the file exists, the container is ready for use and if the file doesn’t exist, the container is busy and not ready.

```
‘ livenessProbe:
    exec:
        command:
            - "cat"
            - "/tmp/healthy"
    periodSeconds: 5 ‘
```

Similarly, for a readiness probe, the following should be included in a yaml file: -

```
 ‘ readinessProbe:
    exec:
      command:
      - "cat"
      - "/tmp/ready"
    periodSeconds: 5 ‘
```

Please find below the documentation link for more reference on the probe configuration for container: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-readiness-probe

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-liveness-probe

Comment: I am using liveness and readiness probes on every container within my container group. My issue is if you set up a TCP probe in traffic manager and the container instance is up and running regardless of the state of the containers in the container group it will return a UP status as the TCP handshake is happening with the container host and not the container the port is mapped to. Updated post with an image.

Comment: Please access your container with <protocol>:// host:port/path, so you can configure your health probe to match the TCP flow. Since, the TCP probe configured in the traffic manager might be blocked to mark up your instance.